# HTTP/Rest find out what content-types are available on a server

Tags: rest, http, content-negotiation

I'm building a REST client, and I would like to be able to ask a server what kind of Content-Types (via `Accept`) it's willing to support.

Is there a standard header (maybe returned from `HEAD` or `OPTIONS`) that a server *could* use to communicate this?

Comment: That information is to be returned in the HEAD, yes, but that's all I recall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most correct way, but the best way I've found to express this now is via a link header with the `alternate` relation type:

```
Link: </someresource>; rel=alternate; type="text/html"
```